# How to combine wildcard and not selectors in CSS

Tags: html, css

Imagine you have a div in one of three possible states.

```
<div id="apple" />
<div id="apple" class="expanded" />
<div id="apple" class= "collapsed" />
```

How can you explicitly target the #apple div only when the expand AND collapse classes are NOT present?

What I came up with is `#apple :not[id$="ed"]` but it's not working. Is it possible to combine both these selectors?

Note: For this scenario it's not enough to directly style #apple. The selection has to be explicitly for only when the expand and collapse classes are NOT there. The only browser that needs to be supported is a current release of Chrome.

Comment: Note: `[id$=...]` and `class=...` don't really match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#apple:not(.expand):not(.collapsed)` will work.

Answer (score 3):

```
#apple:not(.expanded):not(.collapsed)
```

However, it's not valid to have multiple `id=apple` elements.  Technically, you could also do: `#apple:not([class~=expanded]):not([class~=collapsed])`.  To be even more general, perhaps `#apple:not([class])`

Comment: You wouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. It's the same DIV, I'm just showing you watch it would look like in three different states. Those states are being changed/controlled by JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute selector `[class]` to target any class.

Since you want to use `:not` then you can do something like this

`#apple:not([class])` which selects `#apple` only if it doesn't have any classes.

Working example:

```css
#apple:not([class]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="apple">no class</div>
<div id="apple" class="expanded">expanded class</div>
<div id="apple" class="collapsed">collapsed class</div>
```